# MVC - is this correct?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use the MVC Pattern for the first time.
And I'm not sure if i do it the right way:

Main Class:

```
public class DBEditorMain 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    DBEditorController control = new DBEditorController(new DBEditorView());
  }
}
```

DBEditorController constructor:

```
public DBEditorController(DBEditorView view)
  {
    this.view = view;
    addListeners ();
    view.setVisible (true);
  }
```

DBEditorController addListeners():

```
private void addListeners()
  {
    view.addWindowListener (new WindowAdapter ()
    {

      @Override
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      {
        terminate ();
      }
    });
    view.addActionListeners (this);
  }
```

DBEditorView Constructor:

```
public DBEditorView()
  {
    super ("Database");
    setSize (800, 600);
    setResizable (false);
    initGUI ();
  }
```

DBEditorView addActionListeners():

```
  public void addActionListeners(ActionListener l)
  {
    closeButton.setActionCommand ("close");
    saveButton.setActionCommand ("save");
    closeButton.addActionListener (l);
    saveButton.addActionListener (l);

  }
```

DBEditorController actionPerformed():

```
@Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    switch (e.getActionCommand ())
    {
      case ("save"):
        save();
        break;
      case ("close"):
        terminate();
        break;
    }
  }
```

I think i did it right since the View and Model (not implemented yet) have no references to the Controller or to each other.
Is this a good start or have I missed something.

I know this is a dumb "question" ._.

Comment: It isn't a bad approach but If you change the View for a web environment for example, this controller can't be used, since it is dependent of Swing framework.

Comment: since I don't want a web application, this is okay I guess.

Comment: Well, the goal of this pattern is as much separate layers as capability of interchange them. But if you are sure that you won't change the view, yes, it is okay.